# Python 2.7 & MySQL Ubuntu Installation - ZipImportError

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, installation, python-2.7

I already have MySQL5 installed on my Ubuntu 10.
I have installed python2.7 with these commands:

```
$ tar xfz Python-2.7.1.tgz
$ cd Python-2.7.1
$ ./configure && make && sudo make install
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/python
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

I read that I need mysqldb also. So I tried to install mysql-python:

```
$ tar xfz MySQL-python-1.2.1.tar.gz
$ cd MySQL-python-1.2.1
$ python setup.py build
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

And got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

Tried to install setuptools:

```
$ sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
```

And got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

Isn't zlib supposed to be bundled with default python installation ?

Comment: btw. why don't you install packaged one using `apt-get`?

Comment: I think I should've done that from the beginning but I simply followed the instruction installations of Django & Python. Also I was thinking that maybe all the packages was not systematically featured in Ubuntu. Feel free to correct my answer below with apt-get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run this command in python folder

```
$ ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

what you are actually doing is building the the pythonn from source and then installing. So just basically re-run the process for installing python again .

You can first

```
sudo apt-get remove python
```

Comment: Removing system Python may break vital Ubuntu programs that depend on it.

Comment: Right, we can't remove python, but installing all properly with apt-get worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to install libz-dev or zlib-dev or whatnot before building Python.

Comment: I have **sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev**. then do I need to reinstall python ?

Comment: No, you have to rebuild it first.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to compile Python yourself. Here's the **simplest** solution:

1. Install [ActivePython](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/mysql-python/) to `/opt/ActivePython-2.7`
2. Open Terminal and run `/opt/ActivePython-2.7/bin/pypm install mysql-python`